# Error says im not using the things i type c#

Tags: c#, boolean

hi i am trying to make a tic tac toe game. there are lots of codes and inspiration on the internet but i need to make it in a certain way, and it seems that not many use that way, and im having trouble with it. I need to use arrays, and then say that my x = 10 and my y = 1 and whenever i get a sum of 30 or 3 i will know which of these has won.

1. But there is something wrong couse it says under the method of winnercheck that a get or set acsessor is expected and i dont know what that is??
2. besides it keeps warning me that i have define x to be 1 and o to be 10, and my player2 and never use themand
3. I dont know how i can get it to do as i said with summing up numbers too ?

here is my code

```
namespace tictactoe
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
         bool player1 = true;
         bool player2 = false; 
         int x=1;
         int o=10;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            value();
        }

        private string[] status;

        private void value()


        { 



            int[] status = new int[9];
            myarrays();

        }


        private void myarrays()

        {  
            button1.Text = status[0];
            button2.Text = status[1];
            button3.Text = status[2];
            button4.Text = status[3];
            button5.Text = status[4];
            button6.Text = status[5]; 
            button7.Text = status[6];
            button8.Text = status[7];
            button9.Text = status[8];

        }




        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
        }





        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (player1 == true)
            {
                player1 = true;
                button1.Text = "X";
                player1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = true;
                button1.Text = "O";
                player2 = false;
                player1 = true;
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (player1 == true)
            {
                player1 = true;
                button2.Text = "X";
                player1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = true;
                button2.Text = "O";
                player2 = false;
                player1 = true;
            }

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (player1 == true)
            {
                 player1 = true;
                button2.Text = "X";
                player1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = true;
                button2.Text = "O";
                player2 = false;
                player1 = true;
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (player1 == true)
            {
                 player1 = true;
                button2.Text = "X";
                player1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = true;
                button2.Text = "O";
                player2 = false;
                player1 = true;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (player1 == true)
            {
                 player1 = true;
                button2.Text = "X";
                player1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = true;
                button2.Text = "O";
                player2 = false;
                player1 = true;            }
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (player1 == true)
            {
                 player1 = true;
                button2.Text = "X";
                player1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = true;
                button2.Text = "O";
                player2 = false;
                player1 = true;            }
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (player1 == true)
            {
                 player1 = true;
                button2.Text = "X";
                player1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = true;
                button2.Text = "O";
                player2 = false;
                player1 = true;            }
        }

        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (player1 == true)
            {
                 player1 = true;
                button2.Text = "X";
                player1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = true;
                button2.Text = "O";
                player2 = false;
                player1 = true;            }
        }

        private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (førstespiller == true)
            {
                if (player1 == true)
            {
                 player1 = true;
                button2.Text = "X";
                player1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                player2 = true;
                button2.Text = "O";
                player2 = false;
                player1 = true;
            }
        }


        private void checkwinner 
        {
        if (button1.Text =="X" & button2.Text =="X" & button3.Text= ="x")
            MessageBox.Show
            MessageBox.Show


        }


        private void button10Newgame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            button1.Text = "";
            button2.Text = "";
            button3.Text = "";
            button4.Text = "";
            button5.Text = "";
            button6.Text = "";
            button7.Text = "";
            button8.Text = "";
            button9.Text = "";
            player1 = true;
            player2 = false;
        }




        }

}
```

Comment: list the related codes only, please

Answer (score 2):

```
private void checkwinner
```

needs to be `private void checkwinner()`

Comment: And also needs to have the appropriate { }'s around the if block.

Comment: And also actually calling `MessageBox.Show(...)` might help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code, but I think the warning you referenced in the title has to do with this line:

```
int[] status = new int[9];
```

You are creating a new variable but never actually using it, the `status` variable inside `value` only exists within the scope of that method. While the `status` variable within `myarrays` references the member field `string[] status`.

Comment: so what do i do to solve it ? i need to use int[] status = new int[9]; because i have to do something to make the program read my x as 10 and o as one and then by that make it know that whenever i have the sum 3 or 30 that will be three in a row and also a win situation...do u have any idea on how it should look like? it will think so that if my button1+buttun2+button 3 =30 or  x wins and =3 O wins

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's kinda hard to tell exactly what you want to do. From the looks of it you don't need the `string[] status` field at all either since you're directly storing the game state in the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your first question only -

```
MessageBox.Show
```

should be something like -

```
MessageBox.Show("you won!");
```